# Web2py: IntegrityError('NOT NULL constraint failed:post.message

Tags: sqlite, web2py

I thought I had escaped/ solved this error. But now am stuck. My db.py code:

```
Post = db.define_table('post',
                       Field('message', 'text', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(), notnull=False),
                       Field('answers', 'text', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(), notnull=False), 
                       auth.signature
       )
Post.is_active.readable=False
Post.is_active.writeable=False
```

controller:

@auth.requires_login()

```
def index():
    db.post.answers.writable=False
    db.post.answers.readable=False
    form = SQLFORM(post, formstyle='divs')
    if form.process().accepted:
        pass
    messages = db(post).select(orderby=~post.created_on)
    .......code
    #after several codes in now need to post a message to answers field, WITHOUT using a form in the view page
    db.post.insert(answers=report)
```

In my view:

```
{{for msg in messages:}}
code
{{=msg.message}}
{{report from answers field}}
```

My issue is that i keep getting the error:  IntegrityError('NOT NULL constraint failed:post.message

How do I solve this error? 
Kind regards

Comment: Did you initially have `notnull=True`, and now you no longer want that restriction?

Comment: Yes I did have it

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/web2py@googlegroups.com/msg12879.html..... This post did the trick...... The default =''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the database table was originally created with `notnull=True`, later changing the model to `notnull=False` will have no effect, as removing the `NOT NULL` constraint requires an external tool (the DAL cannot remove such constraints).

As you suggest in your comment, you can instead set the default value for the field to something like an empty string, but if you do in fact want to allow null values, you should instead use a database administration tool to remove the constraint from the database schema.